# Add all buttons from my form to a list

Tags: c#, winforms, list, button, addition

I have 86 buttons in my windows form. I have made a list of buttons in my code. Now I want to add all the buttons to the list. Is there a way to add al the buttons to the list in one time or do i need to add everything button by button?

this is my list: `List<Button> lColors = new List<Button>();`

Comment: Is it too late to ask why 86 buttons on a single form makes _any sense at all_?

Comment: @DonBoitnott, it's never too late to ask such a question. Whether the OP will listen and rationalise his UI though is a whole different question.

Comment: I need to control an LED panel wich has 86 different modules and every module needs to have there own color so therefor I used 86 button(+ save buttons etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if all buttons are on form (not in a `Panel` for example)

```
List<Button> lColors = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
```

if some buttons are on form and some are in a panel

```
List<Button> lColors = this.Controls.OfType<Button>()
               .Concat(this.panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>())
               .ToList();
```

Comment: ...and if they were, you would then need a recursive function.

Comment: @DonBoitnott, in some situations, yes. But if a function scans Controls collection of all childs recursively, there can be situations, that it finds unexpected buttons from custom user controls

Comment: This allowed me to gather up a control set of child controls, loop them and access my methods and act on them accordingly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following recursive method to get all child controls of a specified type for specified control:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> GetAllControls<T>(Control control)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.OfType<T>();
    return control.Controls.Cast<Control>()
        .Aggregate(controls, (current, c) => current.Concat(GetAllControls<T>(c)));
}
```

Usage:

```
var buttons = GetAllControls<Button>(this);
```